# i want to make a comment system by using php and notepad

Tags: php, html, wampserver, notepad, comments

i want to create a simple comment system and i want to use the notepad or access to save the database (COMMENTS )  , 
i tend to use this codes below but it didnt work ,  I WANT TO ASK 
1- IS IT RIGHT TO USE NOTEPAD FOR IMPLEMENT PHP CODES ? 
2- IS IT RIGHT TO WRITE THE ALL PATH OF DESIRED FILE (WHICH I WILL SAVE ON IT ) ? 
3- WHY THE COMMENT DIDNT SAVED IN THE NOTEPAD .

```
<?php
if ($_post)
{ 
    $name = $_POST('name');
    $content = $_POST('commentcontent');
    $handle = fopen("C:\Users\User\Desktop\simester8\text.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($handle,' $name  ', ' $content ');
    fclose($handle);


}



?>
```

Comment: ENABLE ERROR_REPORTING and you will discover the various mistakes in your code.

Comment: And if you want a file based db sqlite would be a much better option

Comment: That will fail horribly if you get two users at once.

Answer (score 2):

1. you could use mysql database
2. you don't have to
3. check out this page : http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {    
   $handle = fopen("text.txt", "a+") or die("can't open file");
   $name   = $_POST['name'];
   $content = $_POST['commentcontent'];
   fwrite($handle, $name , $content );
   fclose($handle);
   }

   <form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
   <input type=text name="name" id="name">
   <input type=text name="commentcontent" id="commentcontent">
   <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
   </form>
   ```

Comment: when i save the notepad should i make the extent .html ?

Comment: Up to you. the script writes html files as well. The code I post should be in a php file . Don't foget to add <?php and ?> but you know that already .

Comment: i make it like this  <<?php

<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
$handle = fopen("text.txt", "a+") or die("can't open file");
$name   = $_POST['name'];
$content = $_POST['commentcontent'];
fwrite($handle, $name , $content );
fclose($handle);
}

?>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type=text name="name" id="name">
<input type=text name="commentcontent" id="commentcontent">
<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: and then save it in notepad , the extend is html , cause i dont have  wamp  , and still ,when i press submit it didnt submit any thing

Comment: and the file testfile.text in the same folder with this page i made it

Comment: $handle = fopen("testfile.text", "a+") or die("can't open file");  check file names !

Comment: ok i check it , after i click on submit 
its appears that there is an ERROR , not found <and it  indicate to 
 <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">